# Font family used in creating inserted document

Tags: fonts

I'd be happy if someone could tell me the font family used in creating this document.

[avoid eqnarray!](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf)

Thanks

Comment: It's URW Palladio, a clone of Palatino.

Comment: You can download the class file here: http://tug.org/pracjourn/stylefiles.html